# Couldn't compile build file in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to get back into my program but it gives me this error and I don't know how to fix it.
[image: The error]

Comment: Hi Wyatt, in general pasting the code as text, and surrounding it with triple backticks, so stackoverflow formats it is usually much better than screenshots of code and errors

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your parentheses, for example it should look like this :
 `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8"`

Edit : in your case follow up, because you are missing a slash \

```
jvmTarget = "1.8"\n' , follow up with {}
```

Comment: They're also not escaping the new line.